# How can i send a message from ROS to arduino using rosserial?

Tags: ros, arduino, communication, ros-kinetic, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want LED 13 on my Arduino Uno board to glow when I pass the number 100 as command line argument from ROS.
Here is my arduino code:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int8.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

void ledGlow(const std_msgs::Int8& val){
 
  if(val.data==100){
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  }
  else{
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  }
}

ros::Subscriber<std_msgs::Int8> led("led/start", &ledGlow);

void setup() { 
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  nh.initNode();  
  nh.subscribe(led);
}

void loop() {  
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(10);
}
```

I am giving the following commands in the terminal:

1. roscore
2. rostopic pub led/start std_msgs/Int8 100

After giving the second command LED 13 doesn't glow, also RX led on arduino board doesn't blink.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299752/how-can-i-send-a-message-from-ros-to-arduino-using-rosserial?/) by [Prateek](https://answers.ros.org/users/36853/prateek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-08-06**:
Try adding serial output to your Arduino program to determine if the ledGlow callback is being called, if yes check what value is in the message

**Comment by [Prateek](https://answers.ros.org/users/36853/prateek/) on 2018-08-07**:
I tried adding Serial.println("Hello"); inside the callback function but I'm not getting any output on serial output screen. Also, when I try printing something inside the loop, I get garbage value on serial output screen. Please help! @VictorLamoine

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-08-07**:
Make sure to adjust the baudrate of the serial terminal

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. You need to start up your node by running "rosrun your_package your_node" or an equivalent roslaunch command. I assume you're doing that and that the code you quoted is not complete.
2. If your node lives in its own namespace "my_node_ns", then it would try to subscribe to "/my_node_ns/led/start". Make sure to publish to the right topic.
3. Debug by:

- adding `ROS_INFO("test");` or similar in your functions so you know they are being called.
- Using `rostopic list /led/start --verbose` to check if your node is subscribing correctly to the topic.
- Checking your serial ports and USB connection. It seems like a problem with your Arduino connection, not the ROS side.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2018-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Prateek](https://answers.ros.org/users/36853/prateek/) on 2018-08-07**:
Thanks a lot :)

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2018-08-08**:
Sure. Please update what the problem was when you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you running the rosserial node as described in this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Blink that converts the rostopic message and sends it down the serial port. Don't use serial print in your code it will interfere with that communication

---

Originally posted by [nickw](https://answers.ros.org/users/4160/nickw/) with karma: 1504 on 2018-08-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1